# Can I use in RDMA via Infiniband Load/Store access from GPU2-Cores to GPU1-RAM in the different PCIe-Bus?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, multi-gpu, infiniband, rdma

As said here: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect
I can access from GPU0-Core to the GPU1-RAM on the Same PCIe Bus:

- Load/Store
- `cudaMemcpy()`

It named as "NVIDIA GPUDirect v2 Peer-to-Peer (P2P) Communication Between GPUs on the Same PCIe Bus (2011)":
[image]

And I can use RDMA via Infiniband to copy from GPU2-RAM to GPU1-RAM on the different PCIe Bus, it is named as "GPUDirect™ Support for RDMA, Introduced with CUDA 5 (2012)":
[image]

But can I use in RDMA on the **different PCIe Bus connected via Infiniband** both:

- Load/Store (access from GPU2-Core to GPU-RAM)
- `cudaMemcpy()` (to copy from GPU2-RAM to GPU1-RAM)

Or can I use only `cudaMemcpy()` in RDMA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPUDirect RDMA has a single public implementation at this time, which is via Mellanox Infiniband.  You would need to use something like one of the [CUDA-aware MPI systems](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/) to take advantage of it.

You cannot use `cudaMemcpy` to copy from GPU1 to GPU2 in the example you have shown, i.e. you cannot use `cudaMemcpy` to copy directly between GPUs that live in different host systems.